# See the effect of edits on votes

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes, revisions-list

I often like to see the effect of edits on the votes of a post. This can be useful when reviewing, but it can also be an interesting statistic. Besides it is cool to see the effect of your edit on a below average post.

A way to do this, is to is to preserve the amount of up and downvotes of a revision.

Example a clueless user asked a bad question, getting two downvotes. Another user, edited the post making it much better. Now the question got 3 upvotes. (See also the example below). Each revision now shows the amount of votes it has, the moment a new revision is added. The last revision shows the current status.

[image]

I can imagine, it takes some heavy queries, so a restriction for users with 5000+ reputation would be wise.

And ofcourse this can be expanded to the number of answers, and (for questions) number of favorites.

Comment: Sort of doable with the timeline-feature, but that's also rather cumbersome. =)

Comment: And asign the reputation to the editor. Or perhaps not. And...

Comment: @vonbrand, Adding reputation to the editor is a bad idea. The post still has its original poster. You edit to improve the site, not to get the reputation.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe, I was just trying to point out that such a move would lead to (trying to) asign reputation to the editor(s) too. I fully agree that it isn't a good idea.

Comment: It would be interesting to see which of the new ones are reverts of the old ones. However, that would mean storing / querying much more than the score at the time of a revision.

Comment: @tohecz It's done now.

Comment: Can you really link edits and up/downvotes?